# MergZXing-1.1.2 does not work with Livecode 6.5

Tags: livecode

I am stuck on LiveCode 5.5.2 because MergZXing triggers a deployment-time (IOS) error:

```
linking for armv7 failed with Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "___libinfoptr_mergZXing", referenced from: 
-u command line option ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed faith exit code 1 (use -v to ee invocation)
```

Do I have the latest version, is there a work-around?

I have updated to Xcode 5x and running on Mavericks. I also updated my mobile settings on LiveCode 6.5.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't have the latest version of mergZXing which is built against iOS 7 SDK. It's available from the downloads page on mergExt.com.